# Using IF construction in Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

I'm using the construction "if" in HSQL:

```
String q = "SELECT id, name, " +
                "IF (ABS(name) > 0, LPAD(ABS(name), 4, '0'), name) AS tord " +
                "FROM table where city= " + cityId + " order by tord";

    Query query = session.createSQLQuery(q);
    List<Object[]> list = query.list();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
```

And now i want to refactor this piece of code with HQL. How can i do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Option 1.**

Replace IF with CASE:

```
(case when ABS(name) > 0 then LPAD(ABS(name), 4, '0' else name end) AS tord
```

See [HQL documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions) for details.

**Option 2.**

HQL supports native functions. If you encapsulate calculations in custom SQL function you can write something like:

```
select t.*, paddNumber(t.name, 4) as tord from TableEntity t 
where t.city = :city order by tord
```

Have no environment to check but think each result record will be represented as Object[]. Where first element will contain your entity and second will contain tord.

**Option 3.**

If possible, rewrite application logic. There are different ways to add required padding to field 'name' before saving record. This will remove unnecessary calculation in DB during sorting.